# SwiftUI: UI is lagging on conditional font weight change

Tags: animation, swiftui, fonts, tabs, lag

I have this rather simple code, but I am having some trouble with the conditional change of the font weight. The change from `.medium` to `.heavy` and vice versa, does happen, but it’s lagging.

I am not sure if "lag" is the right word to describe it.

**Any ideas on how to fix this?**

```
struct Playground: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = "Liked"
    var tbs = ["Liked", "Reading", "Ended"]
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(tbs, id: \.self) { tab in
                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 1) {
                        Text(tab)
                            .font(.system(size: 16, weight: selectedTab == tab ? .heavy : .medium, design: .rounded))
                            .foregroundColor(tab == selectedTab ? .red : .blue)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation(.spring()) {
                                    selectedTab = tab
                                }
                            }
                            .padding(.bottom, selectedTab != tab ? 1 : 0)
                    
                        if tab == selectedTab {
                            Rectangle()
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                                .frame(width: 20, height: 1)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 5)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The weird behavior you're talking about comes from the `.spring` animation.

Comment: But `.easeIn` seems to do the job if you want to keep the animation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the font change to be more instantaneous then you can disable the animation for the font:

```swift
    Text(tab)
        .font(.system(size: 16, weight: selectedTab == tab ? .heavy : .medium, design: .rounded))
        .animation(.none, value: selectedTab) // <-- HERE
        .foregroundColor(tab == selectedTab ? .red : .blue)
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.spring()) {
                selectedTab = tab
            }
        }
        .padding(.bottom, selectedTab != tab ? 1 : 0)
```

Or, instead of completely disabling the animation, you could apply a different and perhaps shorter animation to the font change:

```swift
        .foregroundColor(tab == selectedTab ? .red : .blue)
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.1), value: selectedTab)
```